# How to replicate the "New changes since you last viewed" diff in the command line

Tags: git, github

When doing code reviews on GitHub, I usually like to review the code locally.
This allows me to take advantage of my normal development tools for code navigation, linting and so on.

Given a Pull Request from a `topic` branch into `master`, I can get a diff equal to the one on GitHub with:

`git diff $(git merge-base topic master) topic`

To integrate this nicely with the IDE, my current workflow looks like this:

- Change my work tree to match the tip of the PR
  `git checkout topic`
- Soft reset all changes made in the topic branch
  `git reset $(git merge-base HEAD master)`
- Add all files to the staging area (this step is very specific to my setup is only necessary so that IntelliJ shows new files in the local changes)
  `git add -A`

---

However, this doesn't work for the recent partial PR diff that GitHub has with the *"New changes since you last viewed"* feature (available through the URL template `http://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/pull/<PULL>/files/<START>..<END>`)

My naive approach was to simply do a `git diff <START>..<END>`, but this doesn't work when there is a merge from the `master` into `topic` somewhere between `<START>` and `<END>`.
In these cases the diff includes all changes made in the `master` branch since `topic` diverged, while I'm only interested in changes that will be introduced by merging `topic` into `master`.

Somehow GitHub is excluding changes introduced by merges from the base branch.

How can this be reproduced in the command line?

Comment: Try with 3 dots in the middle: `git diff START...END`

Comment: From what I understand from the [revision selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) documentation, 3 dots select all the commits reachable from `START` and `END`, but not both.

In this case, since `END` represents work done on top of `START`, it would just select commits done after `START` (which is equivalent to the 2 dot notation in this case)

Comment: Actually, for the changes since you last viewed, `START` and `END` both should be in the topic branch, so other stuff merged into master should not show up. But I guess the `START` and `END` you are using are not both in the topic branch. But why not?

Comment: Both `START` and `END` are in the `topic` branch.

The problem occurs when `master` is merged into `topic` for some reason (either pull recent changes or resolve conflicts).

In this case, the diff between `START` and `END` show all the changes introduced with the merge `master -> topic`

Comment: My bad, I see. Ok, so the big difference between `..` and `...` is that with `...` you won't see the changes that were merged into `master`. You will see only the changes that your topic branch will bring to the master.